# Accessing variables inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stuck whilst using a loop to calculate the distance between particles. I have the code below so far. I can't seem to access any point other than the last entered one. The print at the end just prints the last one.

Is there any way to access the inputted location for points other than the last one inputted?

```
#user location
xu = int(input('X coordinate of user: '))
yu = int(input('Y coordinate of user: '))
zu = int(input('Z coordinate of user: '))
#number of particles
count = int(input())
icount = 0
while icount < count:
    x=  int(input('particle x coordinate: '))
    y = int(input('particle y coordinate: '))
    z = int(input('particle z coordinate: '))
    q = int(input('particle charge: '))
    icount += 1
print( x, y, z)
```

Comment: Since you defined xu,yu,zu, why don't you use those variables anymore? These should have your first values.

Comment: i think you want a list here and append values to that list

Comment: You need one indentation for the line print(x,y,z). That is , insert one tab space before last print. Once you are able to get the values, store as needed.

Comment: To clarify: every time you do a new `x= input ..` the old value of `x` gets overwritten, as it can only store one single value.

Comment: in each loop value of x,y,z will be overwritten by new inputs, so last loop value will persist at end

Answer (score 0):

Your variables x, y and z are only single integers. If you want to store multiple values with an index to distinguish them you need to instead use a list.

Lists are usually what you want when you are performing a series of similar operations in a loop. An example on how to do this follows, keeping as close to your code as possible otherwise:

```
# user location
xu = int(input('X coordinate of user: '))
yu = int(input('Y coordinate of user: '))
zu = int(input('Z coordinate of user: '))
# number of particles
count = int(input())
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
Q = []
icount = 0
while icount < count:
    X.append(int(input('particle x coordinate: ')))
    Y.append(int(input('particle y coordinate: ')))
    Z.append(int(input('particle z coordinate: ')))
    Q.append(int(input('particle charge: ')))
    icount += 1
for x, y, z, q in zip(X, Y, Z, Q):
    print(x, y, z, q)
```

In essence we are making some lists to hold the values for **all** the particles the user enters then using a for loop to print each of them, not just the last value held.

The code in the question was just assigning different values over and over to the variable, each time discarding the former value.

Comment: @AdamSmith I have tested the code now, it should work. I was trying to quickly demonstrate the concept to the OP without having to find a python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it will never print anything but the last points.

You are iterating through the entire collection, and once you finished iterate, the only values stored in your `x`, `y`, `z` are those contained in your last element you came through.

**Why is that?**

Because, every time you store the new values, you overwrite the older one.

If you include your `print` call in the loop, you will display all the values :

```
while icount < count:
    x = int(input('particle x coordinate: '))
    y = int(input('particle y coordinate: '))
    z = int(input('particle z coordinate: '))
    q = int(input('particle charge: '))
    icount += 1
    print( x, y, z)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to save each `x`, `y`, `z`, and `q` as you iterate through the `while` loop? You'll need to append those values to a list (maybe as a dictionary?) to do that.

```
count = int(input())

loop_list = []
for _ in range(count):  # this is equivalent!
    x = int(input('particle x coordinate: '))
    y = int(input('particle y coordinate: '))
    z = int(input('particle z coordinate: '))
    q = int(input('particle charge: '))
    loop_list.append({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'q': q})
    # toss the dictionary of values into the list
```

Then afterwards you can access it by doing something like:

```
loop_list[3]['y']
# the "y" input on the 4th iteration of the loop
# (4th? remember zero-indexing!)
```

Why these strange doubled-up brackets? Because `loop_list` is a list full of dictionaries. `loop_list[3]` points at the 4th dictionary, then `['y']` gets the value from key `'y'` in that dictionary.